# Decompose grid into rows and columns

Tags: algorithm

Currently I'm working on an algorithm for laying out plots and widgets on a grid. The underlying library I'm using has two primitives for building up a grid, rows and a columns. The idea is that I feed it with a grid spec which defines how many grid cells each plot takes up. The individual plots and widgets can take up one or more grid cells but must be rectangular. To make this problem a bit more concrete I will draw a simple 4x4 grid, where each number represents a separate plot or widget:

```
---------------------
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  3 |
|____|____|____|____|
|  4 |  2 |  5 |  5 |
|____|____|____|____|
|  4 |  6 |  7 |  7 |
|____|____|____|____|
|  4 |  6 |  7 |  7 |
|____|____|____|____|
```

By breaking up each part of the grid we can be decompose it into a number of nested rows and columns, e.g. in this example this might look something like this:

```
col1 = column(1, 4)
col2 = column(3, 5)
row1 = row(2, col2)
row2 = row(6, 7)
col3 = column(row1, row2)
grid = row(col1, col3)

# or as a single expression
row(column(1, 4), column(row(2, column(3, 5)), row(6, 7)))
```

Is there an algorithm we can use that will let us decompose this grid into rows and columns like this? I've been playing around with it but anything I've tried starts getting very complex quickly and I suspect I've simply not found a good way to represent and think about the problem.

Comment: What do these spells mean? `col2 = column(3, 5)  row1 = row(2, col2)`

Comment: Each declares a row/column of the plots in the grid, i.e. ``column(3, 5)`` is a column of plot 3 and 5. The rows and columns can be nested as well so, i.e. ``col2 = column(3, 5); row(2, col2)`` is equivalent to ``row(2, column(3, 5))``, which translates as a column of plot 3 and 5, inside a row with plot 2.